# How do you debug multi-thread/process applications with gdb?

Tags: gdb

It seems bp doesn't work at all..

Is this the case for you?

Comment: It works just fine for me. You'll likely get more useful answer if you state your OS and GDB versions.

Comment: @Employed Russian ,what about multi-process applications?

Comment: What about them? If you have a question, please ask it. Guessing what your question is, and answering what we guessed, usually leads to much wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.  Every time a breakpoint is hit, it is important to look at the thread ID information (which is displayed when it breaks) to be sure it is the thread you assume it is.

Comment: do you mean the bp works for all threads within a specified process?

Comment: @DriverBoy:  that is what I mean.  If you want a breakpoint to apply to a specific thread only, a conditional breakpoint is needed.  I've never bothered with that myself.